# Send Push Notifications to Several Devices

Tags: ios, windows-phone-7, blackberry, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm sending push notifications to several devices using a `for loop` but now i need to send bulk push notification which means that i need to send to multiple devices at the same time

Note that i found a for android but i still need the bulk push notification (no loop using a table of devices) for iPhone ,blackberry and windows phone and i use `C# or vb.net`

for iphone i use:

```
  var payload1 =new NotificationPayload();


   SyncLock lockThis
If szPinCode <> "" AndAlso szPinCode <> "" Then
    Dim BBPushRequest As New HttpBBPushRequest(szPinCode, szMessage, szId, Me)
    BBPushRequest.Url = general.fnGetConfig("PUSH_URL")
    BBPushRequest.ApplicationID = general.fnGetConfig("PUSH_APPLICATIONID")
    BBPushRequest.UserName = general.fnGetConfig("PUSH_USERNAME")
    BBPushRequest.UserPassword = general.fnGetConfig("PUSH_USERPASSWORD")
    Dim clientThread As New Thread(AddressOf BBPushRequest.Run)
    clientThread.Start()
    fnIncrementCounter()
    bResult = True
End If
```

End SyncLock

but this does not take an array of devices just a single device..

Comment: What are you using to do the push for BlackBerry?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible to send multiple push as once just like email. You may have detailed [**INFO from Here**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html).

Comment: if it's not possible how come i found a way for android?  if there is a way for android there must be a way for the other devices

Answer (score 0):

I personally use Parse.com to manage\send notifications.

They take care of analytics and push notifications.
You can (very easily) use API\SDK to register devices, and send notification to specific devices(with filters).

https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#top/iOS

Hope it help. (and yes, it's free)

Comment: What do you mean.

Send via the apps itself or via web site?

Comment: i mean i have the push id of the devices stored in a database i have an app that loops these devices and sends a push notification one after the other, but now i need to loop these devices in a table and send push notification to the whole table at the same time so there will be no delay between the push notifications of the devices.